# How to create a table after inserting data in JSP and also save that data to mysql through java

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp

I have built a page of jsp where I have taken inputs from the user and created a table from that input now I have to show that table on another page and also I have to create that table in mysql simultaneously through Java.

```js
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Dynamic table</title>
<script src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">

 var counter=2;
 function addRow(tableID){
  var dynamicVal = 'row'+counter;
  $('#dataTable').append('\
  <TR>\
   <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="'+dynamicVal+'_chk" id="'+dynamicVal+'_chk"/></TD>\
   <TD><INPUT type="text" name="'+dynamicVal+'_col" id="'+dynamicVal+'_col" required/></TD>\
   <TD>\
    <SELECT name="'+dynamicVal+'_datatype" id="'+dynamicVal+'_datatype">\
     <OPTION value="int">INT(40)</OPTION>\
     <OPTION value="var">VARCHAR(40)</OPTION>\
     <OPTION value="char">CHAR(40)</OPTION>\
    </SELECT>\
   </TD>\
  </TR>');
  counter++; 
 }
 
 function deleteRow(tableID){
 /*$('#dataTable').find('[INPUT type="checkbox"]').each(function(){\
 if($this).prop("checked") == true({
 ($this).closest('tr').remove();
 }
 });*/
   
   $('#dataTable').find('tr').each(function(){
   if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked') == true){
     $(this).remove();
    }
    
   }); 
 
 
 }
 
 function createJSON() {
  
 var obj ={};
 obj.table_name=$("input[id=table_name]").val();
 var rowcolms = {};
 var rowcollection = [];
 $('#dataTable').find('tr').each(function(){
  var row = {};
  row.colName=$(this).find('input[type="text"]').val();
  row.dataType = $(this).find('select').val();
  rowcollection.push(row);
 });
 obj.tablecolms=rowcollection;
     /*var col_name = $(this).val("text");
  var datatype = $(this).type("select");

        item = {}
        item ["text"] = "col_name" ;
        item ["select"] = "datatype";

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });
 $*/
   console.log(obj);
   
}

function ajaxcall(){
 $.get.json({
   url: Createdatabase,
   type:"post",
   data: jsonObj,
   success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
   }
 });
}
 

 </SCRIPT>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background-color : #D3D3D3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h4 {
    color : #000000;
    text-align : center;
    font-family: "SIMPSON";
}
form {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<body>
<form>
<h4>Create Your Table</h4>
<form action="servlet/createdatabase" method="post"> 
Table Name: <input type="text" name="table_name" id="table_name"required>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br><br>
<h4>Design Your Table</h4>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

 <TABLE id="dataTable" name="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
  <TR>
   <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="row1_chk" id="row1_chk"/></TD>
   <TD><INPUT type="text" name="row1_col" id="row1_col" required/></TD>
   <TD>
    <SELECT name="row1_datatype" id="row1_datatype" type="select">
     <OPTION value="int">INT(40)</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="var">VARCHAR(40)</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="char">CHAR(40)</OPTION>.
    </SELECT> 
   </TD>
  </TR>
 </TABLE><br>
<input type="button" value="Create Table" onclick="ajaxcall'">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So please can anyone tell that how can I create this table on another page and also in the format of tables and create this table in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

The connection between JSP and MySQL: The below code explains creating a connection first.

```
import java.sql.*;  
class MysqlCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");  
//here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
con.close();  
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
}  
}
```

to display data on the second page, you need to connect to DB again, then retrieve the data , for more information check out this link
[mysql and jsp](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_database_access.htm)

Comment: I cannot assign the table name as you did because I'am taking table name from the user only,so how do i do that?

Comment: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/rating2", "root", "root");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   stmt.execute("create table '" + table_name+ "'(name varchar(20),mobile  integer(30))"); //this will create the table and you can perform operations on it too after the create query

Comment: Can you also tell me the manifest file to connect theese to because iam unable to connect this
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>Createdatabase</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>Createdatabase</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
      
    <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>Createdatabase</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>servlet/Createdatabase</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
iam using this

Comment: So you are using XML based ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for creating a table from JSP, connection is also established with mysql

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Creating a Table</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Creating a Table</H1>

        <%  
            Connection connection = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:data", "userName", "password");

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                String command = "CREATE TABLE Employees (ID INTEGER, Name CHAR(50));";
                statement.executeUpdate(command);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println("An error occurred.");
            }
        %>
        The Employees table was created.
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```